# Biztalk mapping, creating string[] from string

Tags: mapping, biztalk, biztalk-2009

In a biztalk map, the source schema has a string and the destination schema is waiting for a array of strings.

I just need to create a string array with just one string but I can't make it.

I tried with a scripting functoid and some inline C#:

```
public Array ArrayBuilder(string param1)
{
    ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
    result.Add(param1);
    return result.ToArray(typeof( string ));
}
```

But instead of an array, the functoid outputs:

```
...
<recipients>System.String[]</recipients>
...
```

Any help?

thanks

EDIT

SOURCE SCHEMAS

Basically a list of SMS (Id, message and phone number). With a loop in the orchrestation I iterate through all the SMS and prepare a SMSSend message. this mapping will happen for each of the SMS in the list (that why I have a counter)

**Phone number is the string Im having the issue**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ADOSybaseWCFServices" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ADOSybaseWCFServices" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:complexType name="SMSBatch">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="IDBatch" type="xs:int" /> 
        <xs:element name="SMSList" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfSMS" /> 
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="SMSBatch" nillable="true" type="tns:SMSBatch" />
<xs:complexType name="ArrayOfSMS">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="SMS" nillable="true" type="tns:SMS" /> 
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="ArrayOfSMS" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfSMS" /> 
<xs:complexType name="SMS">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:int" /> 
        <xs:element name="Message" nillable="true" type="xs:string" /> 
        <xs:element name="PhoneNumber" nillable="true" type="xs:string" /> 
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="SMS" nillable="true" type="tns:SMS" />
```

Counter:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns="http://SendSMS.counterSchema" targetNamespace="http://SendSMS.counterSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element default="0" name="counter" type="xs:int" />
```

DESTINATION SCHEMA

For your sanity, I won't put the whole schema, it is autogenerated from a WCF service

**Recipients is the string array I want to create from the phonenumber string, since I just have one recipient per message**

```
...
<xml>
    <complexType name="ArrayOf_soapenc_string">
        <complexContent mixed="false">
            <restriction xmlns:q1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" base="q1:Array">
                <attribute xmlns:d5p1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" d5p1:arrayType="q1:string[]" ref="q1:arrayType" /> 
            </restriction>
        </complexContent>
    </complexType>
    <complexType name="Submission" abstract="true">
        <sequence>
            <element xmlns:q2="http://mobicomp.com/smsexpress/webservice/server/message" name="contactLists" nillable="true" type="q2:ArrayOf_soapenc_string" /> 
            <element name="deliveryDate" nillable="true" type="dateTime" /> 
            <element name="notification" type="boolean" /> 
            <element xmlns:q3="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" name="notificationRecipient" nillable="true" type="q3:string" /> 
            <element xmlns:q4="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" name="notificationType" nillable="true" type="q4:string" /> 
            <element xmlns:q5="http://mobicomp.com/smsexpress/webservice/server/message" name="recipients" nillable="true" type="q5:ArrayOf_soapenc_string" /> 
            <element xmlns:q6="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" name="sender" nillable="true" type="q6:string" /> 
            <element name="validity" type="int" /> 
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</xml>
...
```

SOLVED:

I used and Scripting functoid with Inline XSLT Template

```
<xsl:template name="recipients">
<xsl:param name="phone" />

<recipients>
    <recipient><xsl:value-of select="$phone" /></recipient>
</recipients>
```

Comment: can you post the schemas as well? Particulary the destination schema.

Comment: Can't you just map a string to the destination element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you look into using an XSLT template for the individual string values extracted by your method.

So, you create your array and for each string, go off and generate the destination Xml.

Take a look at [This Link](http://blogical.se/blogs/johan/archive/2011/06/10/biztalk-mapper-how-to-execute-xslt-statements-and-use-the-result-as-input-to-other-functoids.aspx) which talks about using XSLT templates in your map.

Without the destination schema, that's all I can suggest at the moment.
HTH

Comment: I understand I could make a XSLT that would create a <recipients><recipient>66666</recipient></recipient‌​s> from just <phoneNumber>66666</phoneNumber>

Comment: How do you represent multiple <recipients>?

Comment: that won't happen, I have one message for each recipient, 1-1 relation, the schemas is prepared from one message for multiple recipients,1-N, but mine are personalized

Comment: Ah, I see! I would still recommend massaging you source into the destination form using an XSLT template. If you generate an instance of the destination to get the structure, you can recreate this using the input from source and XSLT. It's the way I would go...

Answer (score 0):

Well, depending on what you're actually supposed to be sending to the destination map, I would probably do something like this:

Assuming you receive a string `flibberdyjibit` and want to make it the only item in a `string[]` I'd do:

```
public string[] ReturnStringArray(string input)
{
    string[] output = new string[] { input };
    return output;
}
```

If you're receiving some kind of delimited string that you need to turn into an array (I'm going to assume Pipes) you'd do something like:

```
public string[] ReturnStringArray(string input)
{
    return input.split('|');
}
```

NOTE: I have not compiled either of these, and there may be syntax errors, but intellisense should help you out there, if there are.

Comment: thanks but the result is the same: System.String[] instead of the string array itself

Comment: based on your updated comment, are you supposed to be filling a parent node with an array of some kind of child nodes?  so `<recipients><recipient>Jones</recipient><recipient>Smith</recipient></recipients>`?

Comment: yes. I have an string "+33344434" that has to be: <recipients><recipient>+3344434</recipient></recipients> but instead of it I can only get <recipients>+3344434</recipients>